# How do I migrate to a RAID10 array without losing data

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I am running Ubuntu 12.04LTS, OS is installed on a small SSD so that should not be an issue when modifying the RAID array(s).

I currently have four 2TB WD Caviar Green drives that I would like get into a RAID10 array (stripe of mirrors, I think). The problem is that I have a little bit over 2 TB of data that I would like to keep, and no good way to back it up. At present, I have them set up as two different RAID0 arrays, and manually copied the data from one to the other just in case.

My other issue is that Disk Utility says that the partitions are misaligned by 506880 and 507392 bytes, and I would like to fix that (if it is indeed an issue at all). I don't really understand the particulars of how Advanced Format drives need to be partitioned.

I do have a 1TB drive in another computer that could be used temporarily, possibly allowing me to have 3 drives to play around with. Not sure if that helps any.

Answer (score 2):

**Before you do anything, BACKUP ALL OF YOUR DATA. I cannot stress this enough. Migrating arrays can be tricky, don't risk loosing your data in the process.**

I would stress out that the only guaranteed way is to back up and verify all your data before trying anything like this, just in case.  I would personally use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to make an image, then convert your RAID, and do a restore afterwards.

Now depending on your RAID controller, if it supports "online capacity extension" it might be possible, but I have not tried it.  As I said, I'd rather be safe, and do a full backup, then you can delete the old RAID array, and create a new one that is configured the way you want.

Another thing you can try, instead of converting to RAID 10, Why not a 4 disk RAID 5? Your read performance will be better.  Plus then your array will end up with a total of 6TB total storage, but the RAID 10 will only be 4TB.  [According to RAID Disk Space Calculator](https://www.icc-usa.com/raid-calculator)

For more information see [RAID Management](http://docs.qnap.com/nas/en/index.html?raid_management.htm)

**Before you do anything, BACKUP ALL OF YOUR DATA. I cannot stress this enough. Migrating arrays can be tricky, don't risk loosing your data in the process.**

Comment: What exactly do you suggest that I back up the data to? The only other drive that I have is 1 TB, as stated in the question..

I'm using software RAID (mdadm)

Comment: You can use Clonezilla, to create an image, image uses compression, you can set compression to high, and try to see if it fits on the 1TB drive, depending on file types.  Also there are other backup utilities that may give you better compression.  You can take a look at [Comparison of backup tools](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)